# Xubuntu lightdm screen fliks

Tags: xubuntu, lightdm, xfce, desktop-background

So on Xubuntu I have a lightdm by default. When system is booted or one is logging out and lightdm starts it blinks after 2-4 seconds.

If I do logout form XFCE4 session for a mentioned period I can see my background, than FLICK and i have my lightdm background (in the case a default one). Login window and the top panel are there from the beginning.

It is a bit annoying as I start to enter the password and then FLICK and I have to enter it again. Not much but annoying.

What to do?